# TypeScript dynamic intersection of objects

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type that is an object (or a tuple) which contains other typed objects. `T[keyof T]` returns a union of the inner objects' properties, but how can I turns this into an intersection of the properties?

```
type Dict = {
  info: { name: string; age: number };
  location: { lat: number; long: number };
};

type DictIntersection = ??? // want { name: string; age: number } & { lat: number; long: number }
```

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+union+to+intersection) before posting, [more here](/help/searching). [Here's a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2FAvFA3gKClOA7AMwHsAuDKPAQwFsIyBnYAJ3wHMBuKS1uigV2oAjCEygBfdtigAbIgkrA4RPGXQyFZPAOFNOsvK03aR4yRMyZQkKAFU8SvABUiASTzAR9CEgcAeGwB8qFBSABQ2UBAAHh54ACb0XHggUAD8UKEA1mQ2AJQoAQBuRHBxUJoQhSK5kTEQ8YmhWWT4BCYu+UUlcTXpLuUUlSIWVtDwSG4eTF4+ysF2Ds6Tnt6Kyr7jwADamRAgRASwiMAAugGSAPQXOFAAeqlAA) with the top answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/) applied to the above.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I eventually found that one in the meantime. It is a bit confusing that the original question asks for the intersection of functions & you also have to use the function type to get the properties in the contravariant position, when the two are really independent.